# Passing an array of pointers to strings into a function

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to pass an array of pointers to strings (names) into a function (foo) and read from it. The below code produces a segmentation fault. Can someone please help me figure out why this code is resulting in a segmentation fault? I want to be able to pass the array names[][] through a function and work with the data like I would if I were using names[][] outside the function.

```
void foo(char *bar[]) {
    printf("%s\n", bar[0]);
}

//---------------Main-------------

char args[][50] = {"quick", "brown", "10", "brown", "jumps", "5"};
int i = 0;
int numbOfPoints = (sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]))/3;

//array of all the locations. the number will be its ID (the number spot in the array)
//the contents will be
char names[numbOfPoints][100];

for(i = 0; i < numbOfPoints; i++) {
    char *leadNode = args[i*3];
    char *endNode = args[i*3 + 1];
    char *length = args[i*3 + 2];
    int a = stringToInt(length);

    //add name
    strcpy(names[i],leadNode);
}

//printing all the names out
for(i = 0; i < numbOfPoints; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", names[i]);
}

foo(names);
```

Comment: lol before I posted I censored the code on my machine but I forgot to change it here. Nice catch thanks.

Comment: I am surprised you didn't get any compiler errors. `names[i]` is not compatible with `char* []`. You should change `foo(char *bar[])` to `foo(char *bar)`.

Comment: I don't get any errors. I run it in code blocks and the exe crashes. It's super frustrating because I never have any leads for the errors.

Comment: `names` is *not* an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the the argument type of `foo` and the way you are calling it. The argument type of `foo`, `char* []` is not compatible with `name`. I get the following warning in gcc 4.8.2 with `-Wall`.

```
soc.c:35:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    foo(names);
    ^
soc.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[100]’
 void foo(char *bar[]) {
```

Change `foo` to:

```
void foo(char (*bar)[100]) {
    printf("%s\n", bar[0]);
}
```

and all should be well.

Comment: Thanks, this works but it just prints out the first element in the array. How can I make it print out any given element in the array?

Comment: You can print `bar[0]`, `bar[1]`, etc.  You can use a `for` loop in `main` to do that. You can also pass `numbOfPoints` to `foo` and put the `for` loop in `foo`.